# how switch to the application clicked on the taskbar?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, default-settings

I am using windows 10, I have many apps on my taskbar:

[image]

When I click on one of the apps, for example google chrome, it shows the several instances it hasof that application:

[image]

The problem is that when I click on any of those `instances as shown above` it just complains, and does not make it active as I wanted it to do.

to achieve this I need to click alt+tab and navigate the several options and stop on the one I want:

[image]

I don't like this, I wish I could just click on the above mentioned `instances as shown above`.

Is there any task settings that I could change to achieve that?

[image]

Comment: What complaint do you get when clicking?

Comment: is there a specific reason you can't aggregate all those different instances of chrome to a single one and just swap between tabs?

Comment: Chrome was just an example. any application in the taskbar behaves the same way.. I wanted to click on any of those application and it becomes active - and this is not happening at the moment. I have other machines where it does happen, so what is wrong with this one?

Comment: As @harrymc asked.. What complaint do you get when clicking?

Comment: We would suggest you to play a little bit with the _Combine taskbar buttons_ options. Change them a little bit. Try each of them one by one and see whether they are producing the results that you want to achieve. Eventually, you come back to the same setting and maybe it will work this time.

Comment: when I click I get a sound complain - and nothing done

Comment: Maybe you should verify your setup. I suggest running `chkdsk` and [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).